# Convert the interest rate $j_{2}=9\%$ to $j_{12}$ equivalent

Tags: finance

> Convert the interest rate $j_{2}=9\%$ to $j_{12}$ equivalent

$j_{m}:$ nominal (yearly) interest rate which is compounded (payable, convertible) $m$ times per year

$\$1$ at $j_{12}=12i$ will accumulate to $(1+i)^{12}$; $\$1$ at $j_2=9\%$ will accumulate to $\left(1+\frac{\frac{9}{2}}{100}\right)^2=1.092025$

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
(1+i)^{12} & = 1.092025 \\
 i & = 1.00736-1 \\
 i & = 0.00736 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence, $j_{12}=12\times 0.00736 = 0.08832\%$

But the solution is $j_{12}=1.5\%$. Where I did wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

---

I made mistake when wrote $j_{12}=0.08832\%$, which should be $0.08832$ only or $8.83\%$. Moreover, I consider that exercise as a compound interest which is incorrect. It should be considered as a simple interest.

Comment: Please explain your notation, what does $j_{12}$ actually mean?

Comment: Added that, thank you to point that @5201314.

Comment: The answer doesn't make a lot of sense here, normally we'd expect $j_2$ to be pretty close to $j_{12}$

Comment: Actually, the topic is asking for the equivalent rates (two nominal rates with different frequencies of conversion are said to be equivalent if they yield the same accumulated value at the end of the year).

Comment: No, @5201314 is right. When I did the math, I got essentially the same answer you got: one has the relationship
$$\left(1 + \dfrac{j_2}{2} \right)^2 = \left(1 + \dfrac{j_{12}}{12}\right)^{12}\text{.}$$
From some algebra, we obtain that
$$j_{12} = 12\left[\left(1 + \dfrac{j_2}{2} \right)^{1/6}-1\right] \approx 8.83\%\text{.} $$

Comment: Your answer helps me to understand my error. Here is the solution provided by them 

"$J_m = i \times m$ Nominal interest rate = 9% per annum. $J_2=9\%$

$J_1 = J_2 \times 2= 9\%×2=18\%$

$J_{12}= \frac{J_1}{12}=\frac{18\%}{12}=1.5\%$." Which concept is corrent? @Clarinetist

Comment: @falamiw I think the excerise is about $\textrm{simple}$ interest and not compound interest.

Comment: Aha, now I see. Yes. I consider it as a compound interest. @callculus. Sorry for that.

Comment: @falamiw No problem. I`m happy to clarify the situation.